# Has the Stack Overflow's "score needed to power" always been the same?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

Stack Overflow has this list to show what power you have given your score. Has it always been the same?

```
   15  Vote up
   15  Flag offensive
   50  Leave comments†
  100  Vote down (costs 1 rep)
  100  Edit community wiki posts
  200  Reduced advertising
  250  Vote to close or reopen your questions
  250  Create new tags
  500  Retag questions
 1000  Show total up and down vote counts
 2000  Edit other people's posts
 3000  Vote to close or reopen any questions
10000  Vote to delete closed questions, access to moderation tools
```

Additionally, did the early users with the Beta badge have some benefit?

Comment: Yeah, we have the BETA badge! You don't! :]

Comment: The information for the current state and the most detailed information for what it enables can be found in *[What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292)* (some of the information is in the footnotes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that list has changed over time.

For example, the ability to show total up and down vote counts is a relatively new feature). Also, there used to be an additional capability at 5000 points to delete comments from a post you own, but that ability was removed (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090416035337/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/general/suggestions/110774-set-a-limit-on-how-fast-users-can-delete-comments)).

A reasonable, though imperfect way of seeing changes to that list is to look at the revision history of the FAQ topic on reputation, available [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/7238/list), or of the original post at Stack Overflow, available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/130656/revisions).

Comment: I think originally at 5000 points you could delete *any* comments. Then it got narrowed to comments on posts you own, and then finally removed entirely. It was way too easy to abuse the privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, it varies between sites; [on SU](https://superuser.com/faq) / [SF](https://serverfault.com/faq):

> 100    Create new tags

And meta is just different again (in every way!)

Comment: Interesting. Might be nice if the lists on SU/SF were sorted by reputation required - looks very odd having that ability sandwiched like this: "250 Vote to close or reopen your questions; 100 Create new tags; 500 Retag questions".

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no extra benefit from being a Beta user other than the badge and the extra time to accumulate reputation.

There was more leeway on the sort of questions that were acceptable in the early days of the site so more subjective and "fun" questions were allowed which might have meant that reputation was "easier" to gain in the early days too - but that would only have a marginal now.