# What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?

Tags: discussion, faq, reputation, privileges

Formerly *Reputation requirements compared*.

What are the reputation requirements for privileges on the various sites in the network?

Also, how do reputation requirements for various privileges compare on different Stack Exchange sites? Specifically, the following types of sites:

- "Full" sites e.g. Stack Overflow, Ask Ubuntu, Gaming, etc.
- Public beta sites, sites without a design, and other sites with "beta" reputation levels
- Private beta sites

...as well as any site-specific differences.

[Return to FAQ Index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931)

Comment: At what reputation can a new user begin to suggest edits? 0? Is it the same on meta?

Comment: @bmike: Probably, since even anonymous users can suggest edits.

Answer (score 83):

## Sites

There are **three main types** of privilege thresholds (sorted from high to low):

- "Full" requirements - used on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/) and larger sites with a design ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/)). These are applied to sites whose traffic and high-reputation user population is large enough. Formerly known as "graduated site" or "designed site" requirements, as this was originally tied to graduating or getting a design, but today it's possible for sites to be both but not have these thresholds. Effective February 2023, these privilege thresholds [are no longer deployed on sites except under exceptional circumstances](/a/387045/377214).
- "Beta" requirements - used on public beta sites, sites without a design, and any smaller site whose traffic and high-reputation user population is not large enough to sustain the "full" requirements above ([example](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/privileges)). Originally, only public beta sites had this requirement set, but today it's possible for any site regardless of beta status to have these thresholds.
- "Private beta" requirements - used on private betas and [this Harvard University site](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

Note that Area 51 [has a unique privilege (level) schema](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) that doesn't fit into any of the above general threshold sets, and therefore is not explained here. However, [Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) uses the "full" requirements above.

Additionally, per-site metas do not have reputation, deriving their reputation straight from their corresponding main site (with some caching).

The **three main types** are covered in the table below. Some minor changes to individual sites are indicated with a † in the table and explained further below.

| Privilege | "Private beta" | "Beta" | "Full" |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Create posts](/help/privileges/create-posts) | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| [Participate in meta](/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) | 5 | 5 | 5 | † |
| Skip lecture on how to ask | - | - | 10 | † |
| [Create community-wiki answers](/help/privileges/community-wiki) | 10 | 10 | 10 |  |
| [Remove new-user restrictions](/help/privileges/new-user)¹ | 1 | 10 | 10 | † |
| [Vote up](/help/privileges/vote-up) | 1 | 15 | 15 |  |
| [Flag posts](/help/privileges/flag-posts) | 15 | 15 | 15 |  |
| Post instantly self-answered questions² | 15 | 15 | 15 |  |
| [Comment everywhere](/help/privileges/comment) | 1 | 50 | 50 | † |
| [Set bounties](/help/privileges/set-bounties) | 75 | 75 | 75 |  |
| [Edit community wikis](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) | 1 | 100 | 100 |  |
| [Vote down](/help/privileges/vote-down) | 1 | 125 | 125 | † |
| [Create tags](/help/privileges/create-tags) | 1 | 150 | 300 | † |
| Vote in moderator elections | - | 150 | 150 | ♦ |
| Association bonus³ | 200 | 200 | 200 | ♦ |
| Shown in network reputation graph and flair | 200 | 200 | 200 |  |
| Shown as "beta user" on Area 51 | 200 | 200 | - |  |
| [Reduced advertisements](/help/privileges/reduced-ads) | - | - | 200 |  |
| Reputation leagues, top x% link in profile | 201 | 201 | 201 | ♦ |
| Qualify for first Yearling badge | 201 | 201 | 201 | ♦ |
| [View close votes](/help/privileges/view-close-votes)⁴ | 1 | 250 | 250 |  |
| Run for moderator | - | 300 | 300 | † |
| [Access review queues](/help/privileges/access-review-queues)⁵ | 350 | 350 | 500 | † |
| [See vote counts](/help/privileges/established-user) | 100 | 750 | 1000 | † |
| [Edit freely, SE and LQP/A queue](/help/privileges/edit)⁶* | 500 | 1000 | 2000 | † |
| No popup asking to comment when downvoting | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | ♦ |
| Non-nofollow link in user profile⁷ | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 |  |
| [Suggest tag synonyms](/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) | 1250 | 1250 | 2500 |  |
| [Vote to close and reopen](/help/privileges/close-questions) | 15 | 500 | 3000 | † |
| [Review tag wiki edits](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) | 750 | 1500 | 5000 |  |
| [Moderator tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools)⁸ | 1000 | 2000 | 10000 |  |
| Reduce captchas | 1000? | 2000 | 10000 |  |
| [Protect questions](/help/privileges/protect-questions) | 1750 | 3500 | 15000 |  |
| [Trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user)⁹ | 2000 | 4000 | 20000 |  |
| [Access to site analytics](/help/privileges/site-analytics) | 2500 | 5000 | 25000 |  |

<sup>† Some site-specific change applies (see "Site-specific changes" below)

- The privilege does not apply at this stage

♦ Privilege is purely reputation-based; being a ♦ moderator does not suffice

¹ post more than eight hyperlinks (50 on Skeptics); less rate limiting; post images†

² compose and post a self-answer to your question at the same time as your question; if you don't have this privilege, you can still self-answer after posting your question

³ +100 reputation on any associated account once you reached this on any site

⁴ see and cast close and reopen votes on own questions

⁵ access the *First questions*, *First answers*, *Late answers*, and *Triage* (SO and Physics only) review queues

⁶ edit posts of others without review; access the *Suggested edits* and the *Low quality posts* or *Low quality answers* review queues

⁷ the website link in your profile has a [rel=nofollow attribute](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327588/4751173) if you have less than 2000 reputation, to make it not count for SEO purposes

⁸ see deleted posts, reviews of others; moderator tools (various information); vote to delete questions two days after closure

⁹ edit tag wikis without review; vote to delete negatively scoring answers; vote to delete closed questions with −3 or lower score without delay</sup>

#### Site-specific changes:

- At the moment, only Stack Overflow, Mathematics, and Meta Stack Exchange require new users to go through a tutorial before being allowed to ask.
- Some sites allow 1-rep users to participate in meta. The list of sites may change, but currently they are:

  - [Ask Patents](//patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
  - [MathOverflow](//mathoverflow.net/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
  - [Code Golf](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
  - [Stack Overflow in Japanese / スタック・オーバーフロー](//ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
  - [Worldbuilding](//worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta)
- On all other sites, you can ask a question about your *own* post on the site's per-site meta with just 1 reputation.
- [These sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258876/377214) require 10 reputation to embed images (everyone can upload and link images, but *embedding* requires reputation).
- Commenting everywhere on Meta Stack Exchange is already [allowed at 5 reputation](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). On Stack Apps, there is no threshold at all.
- On Meta Stack Exchange, the [vote down privilege](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/286150/295232) and the [see vote counts privilege](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/379767/350567) are awarded at 100 reputation.
- The *First questions*, *First answers*, and *Late answers* review queues don't exist on Meta Stack Exchange (and all per-site metas), so on Meta Stack Exchange, the minimum requirement to access any review queue is 2,000. (For this reason, the [privilege page](/help/privileges/access-review-queues) on this site states that 2,000 is the minimum requirement.)
- The following sites have different requirements for tag creation:

  - Stack Overflow: [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
  - Mathematics: [1000 reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
  - Physics: [1000 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
  - Meta Stack Exchange: [500 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
  - Law: [150 reputation](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
  - Stack Apps: only [99 reputation](https://stackapps.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
  - Ask Patents: only [1 reputation](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)
- Running for Stack Overflow moderator requires [3000 reputation and certain badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196308/295232). On Mathematics, the minimum reputation is [1000](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27045/228959).
- On Ask Patents, only [250 reputation](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) is required to edit posts.
- The following sites have reduced requirements for casting close and reopen votes:

  - Web Applications: only [500 reputation](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5227/136642)
  - Ask Patents: only [250 reputation](https://patents.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

#### Privileges not tied to a specific threshold

- To answer protected questions, you need to gain 10 reputation on the site – the association bonus does not count. In other words, the reputation threshold for answering protected questions if you have the bonus is 110, not 10. (Being a ♦ moderator [does not suffice](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7657296#7657296).)

  - This does not apply on per-site metas, where you can answer protected questions if you have at least 10 rep on the main site, [even if you earned it through the association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315982/users-with-only-the-association-bonus-can-answer-protected-questions-on-per-site). (Again, being a ♦ moderator won't allow you to answer unless you have the required rep.)
- For every 1,000 reputation after gaining the moderator-tools privilege, you gain another delete vote. (Delete votes are capped at 30 per day.)
- For every 2,000 reputation, you get one bonus flag per day. (You also gain bonus flags for casting helpful flags.) (Flags are capped at 100 per day for comments and 100 per day for posts.)
- If you have a gold tag badge for a certain tag, you can bindingly close and reopen questions using that tag as duplicates, and can modify the duplicate links on such questions, within limits that prevent gaming the system.

  - Specifically, the privilege works like this: consider all the tags currently on a question. Eliminate those tags that you don't have a gold tag badge for, and eliminate those tags that you were the first one to add in (per the revision history). You can exercise the privilege if and only if there is at least one tag remaining.
- Having a network-wide flair requires at least 200 rep on a specific site; having ♦ moderator or staff rights does not confer this ability.
- Only moderators and staff members may add, remove, or change orange ("moderator-only") tags (e.g., [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)) on meta questions.
- Stack Exchange staff members [have certain privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/344161/377214) that are granted to them with their staff bit, which they can use without necessarily being a moderator, plus some additional privileges that are not granted to any users (including moderators).

#### When reputation thresholds change

When a site's privilege thresholds move from "private beta" to "beta" or from "beta" to "full", or when the individual requirement for a specific privilege is increased, [there is no grandfathering of privileges of any kind](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/139433/179372). You'll immediately be held to the new threshold(s) and lose any privilege(s) you no longer qualify for.

## Chat

There are three chat domains:

- Stack Overflow
- Meta Stack Exchange
- Stack Exchange (everything else)

Your chat privileges are based on your reputation in the respective domain. Stack Overflow Chat and Meta Stack Exchange Chat use your reputation on the respective sites. The algorithm for calculating reputation on Stack Exchange Chat is a little more complicated:

- If you have at least 20 reputation on a single site but lack the network-wide [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus/303118#303118) rights, your SE chat reputation will simply be the sum of all your reputation on all sites.
- If you *do* have the association bonus rights, your SE chat reputation will be the sum of your reputation of all accounts [on which you have at least 200 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186739/295232).
- If you don't have at least 20 reputation on a single site, your SE chat reputation [will be equal to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253487/i-was-able-to-post-in-chat-with-less-than-20-rep) the sum of your rep on all sites, minus the number of sites on which you have accounts, plus 1.

The first and third criteria were implemented to ensure that in order for users to talk in chat, they must have at least 20 reputation on a single site, or have *earned* 20 aggregate rep points overall on different sites (only counting the default 1 for signing up once).

Reputation earned on sites with site-specific chat servers (Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange) [does count toward the total reputation earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329472/does-reputation-on-sites-with-site-specific-chat-servers-count-toward-the-ability) for the general Stack Exchange chat server.

Note that it may take a few hours for your chat reputation to update on all chat servers, so you may have enough rep for a privilege but not have it because your chat profile hasn't updated yet.

| Chat privilege | Reputation |
| --- | --- |
| [Chat and show avatar](/help/privileges/chat)* | 20 |
| [Create a chat room](/help/privileges/chat-rooms) | 100 |
| [Create a gallery chat room](/help/privileges/gallery-chat-rooms) | 1000 |
| Review chat flags | 10000 |

<sup>* [Show your actual avatar instead of an "anonymous" avatar in chat rooms](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/239291/377214).</sup>

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't that different from the other sites. There are more sites with a deviating level for tag creation, and running for moderator is the only other difference. I'm going to merge the last two columns.

Comment: What about "comment voting"? in which reputation can one do it?

Comment: @aminabzz Upvoting comments shares the rep requirement with post flagging, so at the moment, it's 15 rep.

Comment: Perhaps cover [edit (incl. tag wiki) suggestion privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366217/when-do-you-gain-tag-wiki-edit-suggestion-privileges)?

Comment: Thanks for putting this together @AdamLear but what about unregistered accounts? [This user has 1000+ rep](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/1684/savir) but still has some restrictions on their account, like not being able to vote, right? Can they participate in elections? Can they set bounties? Can they do all the other things that 1000 rep users can do?

Comment: @user1271772 I believe the main restrictions on an unregistered account are that it's incredibly easy to lose access to one and unregistered users can't vote. I don't think we've ever had an unregistered user try to become a moderator, but I'm reasonably sure we'd ask for a full signup at that point since we have to be sure that account won't be lost or potentially taken over by someone else.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for your very swift response! So they can't vote, but can they do other things that come with rep, such as approve edits on other people's questions, or offer bounties? Since you said you "believe" these are the only restrictions, perhaps you haven't confirmed what privileges their accounts are restricted from getting?

Comment: This is no longer correct, I believe. Non-designed sites I think can choose to raise their rep requirements. And sites like Quantum Computing have a design, but lower rep requirements (not sure if they will raise that).

Comment: @Laurel we can simply choose to raise our rep rep requirements (for example 25k for seeing site analytics, instead of 5k)?